# How can I convert the value written in HTML input to the string variable?

Tags: javascript

```js
var imie = document.getElementById("imim");

function wypisz_imie() {
  document.getElementById("powitanie").innerHTML = "Czesc!" + imie;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My city v1.0</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="skrypt.js"></script>
  <h2>Wpisz jak masz na imie</h2>
  <input type="text" id="imim" value="" />
  <input type="submit" id="potwim" value="potwierdz" onclick="wypisz_imie()" />
  <h1 id="powitanie"></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for my English cause i'm from Poland and i'm new user. I'll be thankfull for answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById("imim").value` to get the text in the text field. It's up to you what to do from there!

Comment: It didn't worked. Opera showed me something like this: Hi! null

Answer (score 0):

imie will return the input element so you should use value property like this:

```js
var imie = document.getElementById("imim");
function wypisz_imie()
{
    document.getElementById("powitanie").innerHTML = "Czesc!" + imie.value;
}
```

imie.value will return the value of input.
[check w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp).

but every time the value will return "", to solve this problem you should access input every time call function to return input with new value like this:

```js
function wypisz_imie()
{
    var imie = document.getElementById("imim");
    document.getElementById("powitanie").innerHTML = "Czesc!" + imie.value;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, remember keep going.

Comment: @MohamedMehdawy please accept the answer if it solved your issue.